# Charting with F# does not take in Seq?

Tags: f#, charts, f#-interactive

Following this from the [Real-World Functional Programming blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297095) about drawing bar and column charts, I was trying to draw a histogram for my data which is stored at a set of tuples (data_value, frequency) in a lazy sequence.

It does not work unless I convert the sequence into a List, the error message being that in case of sequence "`the IEnumerable 'T does not support the Reset function`". Is there any way to generate a histogram/chart etc. using the .NET library from a lazily-evaluated sequence?

Also (ok newbie query alert), is there any way to make the chart persist when the program is run from the console? The usual `System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore` makes the chart window hang, and otherwise it disappears in an instant. I've been using "Send to Interactive" to see results til now.

Comment: I'm wondering why it should be lazy.  If you're drawing a chart, then by definition you must calculate the output to get the chart, and therefore the computation can be eager.

Comment: the values are meant to be read in from a file that takes instrument readings at 2-5 nanosecond intervals. the sizes can safely be assumed to be greater than can fit in main memory.

Comment: But don't you still need "all" of the data to render the chart?  Or are you going to partially render the chart while new data comes in?

Comment: no, entire dataset doesn't contribute to the histogram. I'd just like to know if some variant of the function can accept lazily-evaluated collections (or if the reason for the error is the laziness, or something else entirely that I am missing)

Comment: For a chart window you do `Application.Run(new Form())`

Comment: The chart is not supposed to disappear like that, it should hang around until you close it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that sequences (of type `seq<T>`, which is just an alias for `IEnumerable<T>`) generated using the F# sequence expression notation do not support the `Reset` method. The method is required by the charting library (because it needs to obtain the data each time it redraws the screen).

This means that, for example, the following will not work:

```
seq { for x in data -> x } |> FSharpChart.Line
```

Many of the standard library functions from the `Seq` module are implemented using sequence expressions, so the result will not support `Reset`. You can fix that by converting the data to a list (using `List.ofSeq`) or to an array (using `Array.ofSeq`) or by writing the code using lists:

```
[ for x in data -> x ] |> FSharpChart.Line
```

... and if you're using some function, you can take the one from `List` (not all of the `Seq` functions are available for `List`, so sometimes you will need to use conversion):

```
[ for x in data -> x ] |> List.choose op |> FSharpChart.Line
```

Comment: That's a bit strange though, doesn't normal use of `IEnumerable<T>` mean get a fresh `IEnumerator<T>` for each time you want to iterate over the collection? And `Reset` on `IEnumerator` is documented as "The Reset method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented"

Comment: @NicholasW I agree that that's pretty strange (and very inconvenient). Sadly, the behaviour is inside the .NET charting library that `FSharpCharat` just wraps (arguably, the `FSharpCharat` wrapper should deal with this - i.e. by implementing `Reset` in terms of `GetEnumerator` :-))

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not accept sequences.

That said, there is a good reason for not supporting seq. it is about the structure itself : A seq is just that, a seq, and therefore does not and ***should not***, support the kind of operations needed in drawing a graph. That said, I really wish this stack was more advanced and supported more use style.

So the answer is to

```
|> Seq.toArray
```

or

```
|> Seq.toList
```

before sending to the chart library